# Two array value convert to each pair by PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a two array value :

```
$a = [
     "Oct 01",
     "Oct 02",
     "Oct 03",
     "Oct 04"
      ]

$b = [
     "100",
     "200",
     "300",
     "400"
      ]
```

I want make it this format, How it possible to make below format by php from above  two array....???

```
$result = [
             ["Oct 01","100"],
             ["Oct 02","200"],
             ["Oct 03","300"],
             ["Oct 04","400"]
          ]
```

Here is my full code. Itry to convert above result variable

```
<?php
include '../includes/session.php';
# By Days
$year = '2020';
$monthDays = 'October';
$days = array();
$month = date('m', strtotime($monthDays));
$sales = array();
for ($d = 1;$d <= 31;$d++)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM  sales WHERE DAY(sales_date)=:day AND MONTH(sales_date)=:month AND YEAR(sales_date)=:year");
        $stmt->execute(['month' => $month, 'day' => $d, 'year' => $year]);
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($stmt as $srow)
        {
            $subtotal = $srow['pay_amount'];
            $total += $subtotal;
        }
        array_push($sales, round($total, 2));
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $time = mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year);
    if (date('m', $time) == $month) $days[] = date('M d', $time);

}

$days = json_encode($days);
//echo $days;
$sales = json_encode($sales);
//echo $sales;
```

Trying to make pretty array. Showing error in this side of code.

```
$result =array();
foreach($days as $key => $value){
    $result[$key] = [$value, $sales[$key]];
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: This is pretty straightforward... What have you tried?

Comment: I try with PHP function - array_combine() and array_merge(), but not working ..... !!! Showing error.

Comment: Please show your code and tell us exactly what the error is. The at least we have something to show that you tried. And then we can hopefully explain what went wrong. That's how this site works, usually. You can use the "edit" button of your question to add the information. Thanks.

Comment: #ADyson  Plesae see the code. I have edit my question. And kindly help to fix this error.

Comment: You still didn't actually say what the error is. P.S. I only saw your message by chance because I still had this tab open. If you want to notify someone of your comment, you must put @ in front of their username, not # . :-)

Answer (score 1):

Loop one array and use the key to get the corresponding value from the other

```
foreach($a as $key => $value){
    $result[$key] = [$value, $b[$key]];
}
```

Comment: Not working. Showing this error, ---Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ---

Comment: No it doesn't https://3v4l.org/bgGSV